# Areas in Philadelphia - Safe?

Tags: usa, safety

I am moving to Philly by the end of this month as visiting researcher at Upenn. I am bit concerned about the area before choosing a place to live as I might be living in a shady area that might not be safe, especially at night. Here are some options where I found some places.

1. 46th street Market El Line
2. Upper Darby
3. Bustleton
4. Grays Ferry
5. German Town (But I suppose this is quite far from the city centre.

Comment: Depends on a whole lot of factors, many of which are debatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a range of areas. 46th and Market and Grays Ferry are easy commutes to UPenn, the others are not. I haven't lived in Philly, or worked at UPenn, in a decade, but Grays Ferry is most definitely nicer/safer than 46th and Market. 46th and Market is about as rough as West Philly gets which is about as nice as North Philly gets (sorry Temple). Some people will feel comfortable there, others won't. Most Penn students do not live that far out. Typical student/post doc areas are Pine to Chestnut between 34th and 42nd and anything in Center City (including Grays Ferry). Some post docs live far out (e.g., German Town and Upper Darby), but that is the exception.